# Exporting contact certificates in Evolution

Tags: certificates, evolution

I posted this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556361/exporting-contact-certificates-in-evolution) a couple of days ago, but now think I might have more luck here. Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

I have been searching but unable to find a way to export my contact certificates in Evolution 3.10.4. I made a backup of my Evolution state on my current machine (File->Backup Evolution Data), and then copied it and restored it on my new one (File->Restore Evolution Data). This seems to have worked for everything (accounts, address book, etc.) except certificates. Is there something I am missing? Are certificates something that is separate from Evolution and handled with some other utility when migrating machines?

Comment: That's fine to move it here, but please delete the original on AU. We have a policy of not allowing cross-posts across the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/mail-encryption.html.en

Comment: @sim Thanks for the link, but I'd already read through it and found nothing about exporting certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Question is quite old but I had the same problem and couldn't find anything valuable, so I want to share this in case it might be useful for someone.

I'm using Evolution 3.32.5 on Linux and you can export the certificates

1) in the certificate view (main window → menu "Edit → Preferences" → Certificates).

2) select a certificate, click button "view" and open the "Details" pane by clicking the small arrow.

3) There is an option "export certificate" in the context menu when you right click. In my case and on my platform, this option only shows up the second time you right-click (!!!!!!).

Don't know if this is related to Linux or other setup-related stuff. At first, I thought I hadn't been clicking in the correct area of the details' pane but after trying a bit the "export certificate" option really only shows up at the second right-click.